# how to define Output parameter as character string for Oracle procedure in c#?

Tags: c#, oracle

Here is the simple stored procedure that returns a character string literal

```
PROCEDURE getUserValidateProfileValue (      
  outParam1 OUT VARCHAR2)
AS
BEGIN  
    SELECT 'testABC' into outParam1 from dual;
END getUserValidateProfileValue;
```

this runs OK in Toad.  And following is how I call it from my C# app (note: I have several other procedures that get called using same connection, etc, which all work fine)

```
...
using (OracleCommand command = DaoHelper.GetOracleBoundByNameStoredProcedureCommand(conn, schema, pkg, "getUserValidateProfileValue"))
{
   command.Parameters.Add("outParam1", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 2000, ParameterDirection.Output);
   command.ExecuteNonQuery(); <<<---bombs out here
   s1 = command.Parameters["outParam1"].Value.ToString();
}
```

this bombs out at "command.ExecuteNonQuery();"

how to retrieve this output?

Answer (score 2):

OK -- I found the fix -- you have to include the OracleCollectionType which in my case I set to None:

```
command.Parameters.Add("outParam1", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 2000, OracleCollectionType.None, ParameterDirection.Output);
```

Now my procedure works.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try in place of the current parameter add and see if it helps at all?

```
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("outParam1", OracleDbType.Varchar2));
```

Comment: --it doesn't like "SqlParameter"  -- getting red line.

Comment: Admittedly I haven't used this in a few months, do this rather: `SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            s1 += reader[0].ToString();
        }`

Comment: The proc returns only one value, so a reader would be a little overkill.  But I found a fix anyway -- have to include OracleCollectionType .None to the parameter arg list.